# Как распарсить CSV с лишними запятыми в кавычках?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, csv

имеем строки в файле:

```
"one","two,200",50,"asd_three",0
"one","two00",50,"asd,three",0
```

как распарсить это в переменные типа:

```
a1="one", 
a2="two,200", 
a3= 50, 
a4 = "asd_three"?
```

главной проблемой является нерегулярное появление запятой внутри текстового поля в разных колонках(только в тех, что в кавычках), так что просто split по запятой не прокатит и на кавычки не очень получается опереться, так как не все поля в кавычках.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/5VUHBY/1 как вариант. У Вас так же `0` в конце строки пропал, это так и должно быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов из похожего вопроса со [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv)

Например,

```
(?:^|,)(?=[^"]|(")?)"?((?(1)[^"]*|[^,"]*))"?(?=,|$)

(?:,|\n|^)("(?:(?:"")*[^"]*)*"|[^",\n]*|(?:\n|$))
```